# How can I get all modulo(%) operation in my C source code

Tags: c, static-analysis, lexical-analysis

How can I get all modulo(%) operation in my c source code?
I don't think a regular expression can do it, due to C MACRO inclusion.
And, must take care of string printf formatting.

Which static analyse source code can I use to do this?
For exemple, Codesonar or codecheck "only" try find problems, not that.

I want to check manually all modulo operation with zero. (like division by 0).

Comment: @klutt This won't handle cases like `printf` formatting.

Comment: How many hits do you expect? And to what purpose? If the number is quite below 100, I'd not bother to find a perfect regex but simply look through all hits.

Comment: @DanielKleinstein It will, provided one make sure the regex ignores percent signs within quotes...

Comment: If OP is looking for a robust solution then regular expressions aren't the way to go - C is a context-free grammar and too complex for a regular expression. OP is asking not for all instances of the `%` character but for all usages of the `%` **operator** - I'm fairly convinced this is also a CFG, although I'm not sure.

Comment: @klutt Not in this case: `int x = 0; return 2 % x;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not the best way to do this, but it seems to work. Here's my test file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MACRO %

int main(void) {
    int a = 1%1;
    int b = 1 MACRO 1;
    printf("%1s", "hello");
}
```

Then I ran this and got some useful output:

```
$ clang -fsyntax-only -Xclang -dump-tokens main.c 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep percent
percent '%'     Loc=<main.c:6:14>
percent '%'  [LeadingSpace] Loc=<main.c:7:15 <Spelling=main.c:3:15>>
```

Short explanation:

This is the output from the lexical analysis. The command seem to write to stderr instead of stdout. That's the reason for `2>&1 > /dev/null`. After that I'm just using grep to find all occurrences of the modulo operator.

Comment: Cool!! Similar functionality is probably hiding behind `gcc`'s `-fdump-tree-all`, but far less elegantly (it doesn't seem to export lexing tokens, for instance).

Comment: Thanks, good, is it possible in the output to view the c source code line with a context of 5 lines?

Comment: @DavidBonnin Yes it is. As you can see, this outputs the file name and line number. Filter those two out and use some math with `head` and `tail`